# OpenIndiana Static IP

Tags: ip, solaris, opensolaris, openindiana

I've installed OpenIndiana 151a7 twice now. Configured a static ip using the following instructions:

```
svcadm disable svc:/network/physical:nwam
svcadm enable svc:/network/physical:default
cp /etc/nsswitch.dns /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

/etc/nodename

```
storage
```

/etc/hostname.e1000g0

```
10.0.1.64 netmask 255.255.248.0
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
search lbox.com
nameserver 10.0.1.45
nameserver 10.0.1.46
```

/etc/inet/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 storage storage.local localhost loghost
10.0.1.64 storage storage.lbox.com
```

/etc/inet/ipnodes

```
127.0.0.1 storage storage.local localhost loghost
10.0.1.64 storage storage.lbox.com
```

/etc/defaultdomain

/etc/defaultrouter

```
10.0.1.2

reboot
```

I cannot ping and cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I also tried this alternative:

/etc/hostname.e1000g0

```
10.0.1.64
```

/etc/netmasks

```
10.0.1.0    255.255.248.0
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I can't ping?

Comment: You could start by providing error messages and a description of what happens when you try to ping.

Comment: It's actually a little annoying... I hated this process in OpenSolaris. The key is `svcadm disable svc:/network/physical:nwam`

Answer (score 4):

I used the `ipadm` command. Process documented here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1458/gjwiq.html

Answer (score 1):

I let the OpenIndiana install find its DHCP address and then followed this format

```
echo 192.168.1.1 > /etc/defaultrouter
svcadm disable svc:/network/physical:nwam
svcadm enable svc:/network/physical:default
cp /etc/nsswitch.dns /etc/nsswitch.conf
echo storage > /etc/nodename
echo 10.0.1.64 > /etc/hostname.e1000g0

vim /etc/resolv.conf
    search lbox.com
    nameserver 10.0.1.45
    nameserver 10.0.1.46

vim /etc/inet/ipnodes
    127.0.0.1 storage storage.local localhost loghost
    10.0.1.64 storage storage.lbox.com

echo 10.0.1.2 > /etc/defaultrouter
echo 10.0.1.64 > /etc/hostname.e1000g0
echo 10.0.1.0 255.255.248.0 > /etc/netmasks

reboot
```

And everything worked.

EDIT: no it didn't

Comment: I'm not sure why but it stopped working today.